# Create form to change relationship from related model's form

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Thing(forms.ModelForm):    

class Owner(forms.ModelForm):
    thing = models.OneToOneField(Thing)
```

I want to add a form to change the owner in Thing's UpdateView. I can do it like this:

```
class ThingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Owner.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = '__all__'
```

And then process the result inside `form_valid()` method. But isn't there a more direct approach for this, where i just add this to the `fields` of the form?

**UPDATE**

So I ended up doing it like this:

```
class ThingUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Thing
    form_class = ThingForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(ThingUpdateView, self).get_initial()
        try:
            initial['owner'] = self.object.owner
        except Thing.owner.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        owner = form.cleaned_data['owner']
        owner.thing = self.object
        owner.save(update_fields=['thing'])
        self.object.save()
        return redirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())
```

Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: No, since the relation is in reverse, and Django does not automatically adds the items in reverse.